# How can I implement a Delete and Cancel button in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form to delete a record. One the form I am using a delete button and when the button is clicked the form is submitted.

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
```

How can I implement a cancel and check in the action if it is the delete or the cancel that has been clicked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to give the input a `name`.  For example:

```
<input type='submit' value='Delete' name='action' />
<input type='submit' value='Cancel' name='action' />
```

And then in your Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(string action) {
    if (action == "Delete") {
        // User clicked "Delete"
    } else {
        // User clicked "Cancel"
    }
}
```

Comment: Also to note, a "Cancel" button is usually unnecessary for the Web ... a "Back" link makes much more sense.  The only case where "Cancel" might make sense is if you have a multi-page form that doesn't save changes until the end, so "Cancel" will indicate that all changes will be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to handle a cancel click event in  your controller? You are probably just redirecting the user to a different page when they cancel, right? Javascript has worked pretty well for me:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" 
   onclick="window.location='<%: Url.Action("Details", new { id = Model.Id }) %>'" />
```

Comment: +1 That's what I would do or include confirm dialog box on the event listener depending on whether or not there is the need for redirect.  `onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your comment?')) $.del(@comment.ArticleId, @comment.CommentId, @comment.UserId ); return false">`

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (well, you could do it in just JavaScript too), you could do something like:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?') {
        // do delete
    }
});
```

Comment: I was thinking to put a delete and cancel button on the same screen but not sure how to check which has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

My [Intro to ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs) explains this. Make sure you don't delete on a GET.

Answer (score -1):

In regards to [Stephan Walter's site](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because)...

**MVC application**

What about using using the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute with some authentication in the `ActionResult` to protect against accidental deletes?  What if you are using jQuery GET callbacks with an `ActionResult` that renders a `PartialView`as he suggests that REST purists would defend the idea that GET requests should not change the state of your application? like:

```
//delete comment and make ajax callback
function del(aid, cid) {
    $.ajax("/Article/DelCom?AId=" + aid + "&" + "CId=" + cid, function (result) {
        $('#comments-partial').html(result);
    });
```

Or is this only applicable for links?

Comment: Do not delete on a GET. Do you really want your antivirus software's link scanner or web browsers pre-fetch function (etc) to wipe your data as you browse around?

Comment: I did read this article and there was actually some reason why I suggested this technique I just can't remember why ATM and judging by the time of comment it was probably a long nite. It might have been that I wanted to use ajax and I said get??? Anyways, I do understand that typically the ajax .get callback should only update the content (shouldn't affect the state of the application) upon deletion and if I remember why I went this route I will respond.

Comment: I remember now. What I did was used a get to create an empty object inserted into a form within a partial view so no INSERT was executed. Then I used '@Ajex.BeginForm' to actually persist the data. So this method is fine just not with DELETE so my apologies.